# Plotting Different values in a line in Excel

Tags: excel, charts

**Scenario:** I am trying to plot values in a line: I have Max, Min, lower bound 1, upper bound 1, median value and my "Ret" value (which will change at each row, and each row would have its own line "graph").Each of these data point (max, min, bounds...) do have a numerical value.

**Problem:** I already tried all the graphing options in excel, but can't seem to find any way to get the wanted outcome.

**Question:** Is there a direct way to do that in excel?

**This is what I am trying to achieve** (each row will have one of these graphs, once I find out how to do it, I will write a VBA macro to automate this):

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the best way to do this is to assign a second value to all the rows and instead of plotting as a single column of values, plot each row as a coordinate. This answer came as an advice from a user in another forum, to the same question posted here (goo.gl/icL38d).

For a sample data:

```
Value      X     Y
min       -5     0
max        5     0
median     0     0
lowb1     -2     0
lowb2min  -4     0
upb1       2     0
upb2       4     0
Target     3     0
```

I plotted this as a scatterplot with the coordinates, and configured the target data point to stand out. The result was very close to the originally intended one.[image: wanted chart]